# Elasticsearch Insert new record without overwrite

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I use Elasticsearch Bulk method for a scenario where a I need to index multiple documents and to make sure if the record already exists in elastic, it is will be ignored and not overwritten.

I am looking for a similar method for non bulk scenario. I currently have this method to index the data but it always overwrite the previous record if it already exists. Can anyone help me find out how to index one record and do not overwrite if the record already exists.

```
public IIndexResponse Index<T>(T data, string indexName, string typeName) where T : class
    {
        if (indexName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Index name is null. Please provide index name to insert the data.");
        }

        return Client.Index<T>(data, i => i
            .Index(indexName)
            .Type(typeName)
            .OpType(Elasticsearch.Net.OpType.Create));
    }
```

Comment: The same method started to work now. I might have not compiled it properly :)

Comment: For any document storage DB, if ID is same, it will rewrite the document. So, you just need to make sure that ID is different